# Updating via ajax a DB and show the Answer in a Div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i want a kind Like Button on my Page. I have News and there should be a "hooah!" link (maybe you know it from Battlelog, if you are a gamer) that update my Db via a update.php. Updating is fine but i don´t want the whole page reloaded to show the actual "Hooahs".
At the moment is use a Form to transmit the data - i transformed the Submit-Button that it looks like a Link ...

now my problem :

I want it like "battlelog" you click and then the text shows "5 Persons gave a hooah!"

- it is possible to use the **Hooah!** from "5 Persons gave a **hooah!**" as link? and when clicked it changes to "6 Persons gave a hooah!".

my script :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ajax_form{newsid}').bind('submit', function() {
        var form = $('#ajax_form{newsid}');
        var data = form.serialize();
        $.post('index.php?hooah_update', data, function(response) {
            document.location.reload();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

the form:

```
    <div style="position: relative; top: -16px; left: 515px;">
      <form method="post" id="ajax_form{newsid}" action="#">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{newsid}">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="hooah!" style="background:none; border:0; color:#0099ff; cursor:pointer;">
      </form>
    </div>
```

thx for taking a look ;)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be almost there. Instead of:

```
document.location.reload();
```

You would need something like:

```
$("#your_div").html(response);
```

The php script would have to echo out the text you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to add 1 count on the client side rather than show the actual "Hooahs" count.

Imagine that you open the page and it shows "5 Persons gave a Hooah!", 
Before you click the "Hooah!" button there's 10 other people gave hooahs.
now you click the button, I think it's better to update the count to 6 than to 16 after just one click by you.
Don't worry about the actual count because it will show 16 when you refresh the whole page.

```
$.post('index.php?hooah_update', data, function(response) {
    if(response.success) {
        $('span#count').text(parseInt($('span#count').text()) + 1);
        // Change Hooah to Hooahs
        if(parseInt($('span#count').text() > 1) {
            $('span#hooah').text('Hooahs');
        }
    }
});
```